# Pass by reference implicitly calling copy ctor for incompatible argument?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor

I am working with the following legacy code pattern for debug outputs. I realize this isn't the most efficient way of printing debug messages, but my question concerns something more fundamental. This seems like a basic question, but it challenged my understanding of how function parameters specified as pass by constant reference are interpreted by the compiler.

The pattern for debug messages in the legacy code appears below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>



void debugMsg(const std::string& testStringRef){
    printf("%s\n", testStringRef.c_str());
}

int main() {

#if defined(DEBUG_MSG_OUT)
    char debug_message[512];
    snprintf(debug_message,512, "TESTING 12345678910!");
    debugMsg(debug_message);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Now before this example came to my attention today, I would have said it should not compile because debugMsg accepts a pass by const string reference and it is called with a char[]. But it does compile and outputs the expected string when run.

This challenged my understanding of pass by reference function parameters (which I realize is basic C++ knowledge, but this was new for me). I thought one of the main advantages of by reference function parameters was to avoid copy construction that occurs in pass by value. I would have thought implicit argument conversions on pass by reference parameters would not be allowed, and instead would be a compile error. But to me, it looks like a temporary string object is still constructed even though debugMsg is a pass by reference function.

I was looking at the disassembly of this code and don't see a call to std::string's copy constructor. Can someone clarify what is happening here with the low level details? If in fact the char[] is implicitly converted to a std::string and then this object is passed to debugMsg() why is this allowed to happen in C++ for specific pass by reference functions?

[image: Disassembly debugMsg]

Comment: A `const &` can bind to both a lvalue and a rvalue. One implicit conversion is allowed for function parameters, so a temporary `std::string` is created and that binds to the `const std::string&`. One way to avoid this would be to pass by none-const ref in this case.

Comment: @super \*non-const

Comment: @super: better to mark as `delete` other overload that to be const "incorrect".

Answer (score 4):

This is normal.  If there's a non-explicit eligible constructor, it will be used as a conversion.  Creating a string from a string literal uses the `char const *` constructor.  (That's why you don't see the copy constructor--it's only called if we're copying a std::string, but in this case we're creating one from a literal, so a different constructor is used.)

Your question then boils down to, "I'm surprised a temporary (rvalue) can bind to a lvalue reference to const".  This has been true of c++ since before it was standardized in 1998.  However, the error you expected does exist if you try to bind a temporary to a *non-const* lvalue reference.  The idea is, if it's a modifiable lvalue reference, the function will change its value.  Since writing to a temporary is almost always a bug, and there were no good arguments for doing so, it was disallowed.  But binding a temporary to a *reference to const value* is allowed because it's only used as a read-only input and the temporary lasts at least as long as the lifetime of the lvalue reference that binds to it.  It's useful and safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your conversion of my question to the simplified C++ specific wording makes a lot of sense. Do you think the call to the string constructor to construct the temporary string object is handled in one of the callq with _ZNS in the disassembly shown? I am using Cygwin C++ Compiler and Linker, with the GCC Assembler. But you would think one of those calls before callq debugMsg() would be to construct the temporary string right?

Answer (score 2):

Implicit conversions are a normal part of reference binding. Since the string literal is not a `std::string` a call to the converting constructor `basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() )` is made. This resulting temporary is bound to the reference until the end of the full expression. Naturally there wouldn't be a call to a copy-constructor since we are dealing with references.